# How to resume then send a program back to the background

Tags: background-process, background, job-control

I know I can run something in the background by adding `&` to it, such as `tail -f log.log`

I can then resume or send the job to the foregrond with `fg`

However, once I do this, how do I send it to the background again? `Ctl-z` stops the task, and `Ctl-c` kills it.

When I type `bg` nothing happens.

Comment: ctrl+z and command `bg`

Answer (score 2):

Once you have use `Ctrl+z` to stop the process, you can send it to the background with the `bg` command.  You probably want to take a look at the `jobs` command too.

> help bg 
>   bg: bg [job_spec ...]
>       Move jobs to the background.
>
> Place the jobs identified by each JOB_SPEC in the background, as if they
>      had been started with `&'.  If JOB_SPEC is not present, the shell's notion
>      of the current job is used.
>
> Exit Status:
>       Returns success unless job control is not enabled or an error occurs.

Comment: So the idea is to use `Ctl-z` to stop the process, (and also minimize it) but then typing `bg`  and the job number restarts it?  sorry, I find your answer a bit short.